# How to install xCode11.3 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, macos-highsierra

Currently I am using **Xcode 10.1** on **MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6**, on **MacBook early 2011** with 4GB ram.

> Problem is that I am unable to upgrade my MacOS Version to Catalina,
>   Is it possible to install **xCode11.3** in same **macOS High Sierra**?
>   or any other safe solution for installation of MacOS Catalina in my
>   unsupported MacBook pro early2011 and then to install xCode 11.3?

Please suggest a well tested and safe solution.

Comment: Short answer: No. Xcode 11.3 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14. 4 or later.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your comment, I already aware about the fact that MacBook Early 2011 is not capable of doing that officially it is unsupported, But my problem is that I am in the area which is locked down currently & I needs  to install Xcode11.x on this Mac Machine for at least one month even it is officially unsupported but I needs to work in swift 5.

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded Mac OS Catalina latest version patcher from http://dosdude1.com/catalina/ and installed according their instructions.
After that I've simply used MC OS Catalina Appstore app to install latest version of Xcode, it installed everything which i required, but the meantime speed goes too slow... but it works for me untill I purchase a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you require Swift 5 then you can get away with XCODE 10.2.

You can get 10.2.1 by following https://codewithchris.com/xcode-update/.

I just wanted Swift 5 since I am learning to program in it. Will get a new laptop later.

I have Xcode 10.2.1 running on OS 10.13.6. This means I have Swift 5.0.1. The latest Swift 5.2 requires Xcode 11.4.